# How can I do voice recognition for amazon alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing amazon alexa skill and I want to add voice recognition to it, so when any user talk to Alexa, My skill should recognize the voice and get his information from our database or save his data as a new account in our database, I don't know how to do the voice recognition, do you know any idea about how to do the voice recognition ?

Comment: you can do a word based recognition ( like password ). I don't think there is voice recognize capability given in alexa-skill-kit as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this using the skills kit. Alexa only hands you text and not audio of what the user said. The user can examine what was recorded - but you cannot.

This is likely a privacy measure - giving you access to a voice print of the user may allow a privacy invasion.

If you need to connect a user to your own records, you should look into [Account Linking](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html).